# No rule to make target 'package/helloworld/install'. Stop

Tags: openwrt

I am new to openWRT. I have compiled the openWRT source code by following the steps from [this site](https://www.gargoyle-router.com/old-openwrt-coding.html).

I have created a new component and tried to execute 
make `package/helloworld/install -j1 V=s` in the `openwrt` path and before package folder. The steps looks to be simple, but I am getting an error as No rule to make target `/package/helloworld/insatll` Stop.

Can someone suggest if i have been missing, So I can add any more statements. Blocking at step 1 itself. Your help is worth!!

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: This page was last modified in 06/14/2011, and OpenWRT has shifted dramatically since then. If you google `build openwrt` and click on the third result (OpenWRT was forked into LEDE, but the first 2 Google results reflect old OpenWRT), you should look at https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/build-system/use-buildsystem .

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable called source_dir with the directory address to your code in your makefile. for example:

```
SOURCE_DIR:=/home/johndoe/helloworld
```

also you need to update your package feeds using:

```
cd /home/johndoe/openwrt
./scripts/feeds update mypackages
./scripts/feeds install -a -p mypackages
```

Also that tutorial looks old. Try the hello world example at:
[Hello OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/helloworld/chapter2)